# remove element with click in body or window out of same element in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to delete `<span class="yes-items" id="yes-items">` when the user clicks anywhere on the page except the `<span class="yes-items" id="yes-items">`.

In addition, the checked to remain in `<input type="checkbox" name="Yes" id="okey">` after remove `<span class="yes-items" id="yes-items">`
or when the user clicks No, remove checked in `<input type="checkbox" name="Yes" id="okey">` and `<span class="yes-items" id="yes-items">`

Please help me to do this work. If you have a suggestion for solving this problem, thank you for letting me know. Thank you in advance for your cooperation.

```js
const confirm = document.getElementById('confirm');
confirm.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const yes = document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
  const yesItems = document.getElementById('yes-items');
  if (yes.checked == true) {
    yesItems.style.display = "block";
  }
  document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.yes.checked == true) {
      yesItems.style.display = "none";
    }
  });
});
```

```css
items {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: .5rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

span.yes-items {
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid var(--c1);
  color: var(--txt);
  background-color: #e6eef7;
  top: 20%;
  left: 0;
  width: 94%;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: none;
}

span.yes-items input {
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<p class="items">
  <span class="label">example</span>
  <span class="label-items">
    <label class="label-item" for="okey" id="confirm">
      <input type="checkbox" name="Yes" id="okey">
      Yes
    </label>
    <label class="label-item">
      <input type="checkbox" name="No" id="No">
      No
    </label>
  </span>
  <span class="yes-items" id="yes-items"><span>                                            
    <label for="Diabetic">
      <input type="checkbox" name="Diabetic" id="Diabetic">
      1
    </label>
  </span>
  <span>                                            
    <label for="Diabetic">
      <input type="checkbox" name="Diabetic" id="Diabetic">
      2
    </label>
  </span>
  <span>                                            
    <label for="Diabetic">
      <input type="checkbox" name="Diabetic" id="Diabetic">
      3
    </label>
  </span>
  <span>                                            
    <label for="Diabetic">
      <input type="checkbox" name="Diabetic" id="Diabetic">
      4
    </label>
  </span>
  <span>                                            
    <label for="Diabetic">
      <input type="checkbox" name="Diabetic" id="Diabetic">
      other
      <textarea class="explain" placeholder="Define Other" cols="50" rows="3"></textarea>                       
    </label>
  </span>
  </span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library of npm https://www.npmjs.com/package/onclick-outside . Use it . Do not forget to do the things :

1. npm init
2. npm i onclick-outside or yarn add onclick-outside

Comment: hello my friend. thank you very much. but I have to javascript pure and and I should not use the package.

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot use any package I must say you to do this ->

```
<html onclick="hide()">
 <head>
 Your head stuff
 <style>
.yes-items{
display:block //important!
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
Your code
<span class="yes-items" id="yes-items" onClick="donotHide()"></span>
</body>
<script>
function hide(){
var elementToHide = document.getElementById('yes-items');
if(elementToHide.style.display = "block"){
elementToHide.style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("yes-items").onclick = () =>{ 
elementToHide.style.display="block"}
}
else{
elementToHide.style.display="block"
}
document.getElementById("yes-items").onclick = () =>{ 
elementToHide.style.display="block"} </script> </html>
```

Comment: hello my friend. Unfortunately it did not work